# SSIS Script Task: Send Outlook E-mail (Authentication Method Issue)

Tags: c#, ssis, office365

There was change in the authentication method that made the code below obsolete.

I tried searching the web for something clear and concise on how to fix the error but I couldn't find anything. However, working with my IT team, I was able to update the code and now it works.

Here's the code before the authentication change (note the credential section):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
#endregion

namespace ST_502210b8c9334bfab4b37133997b2a7f
{
            public void Main()
        {
            // C# Script for Script Task in SSIS
           
            String SendMailFrom = "YourUserName@domain.edu";
            String SendMailTo = Dts.Variables["ReceipientEmail"].Value.ToString();
            String SendMailSubject = "Report Title";//Dts.Variables["EmailSubject"].Value.ToString();
            String SendMailBody = "Please see attached";
            string attachFile = Dts.Variables["FileName"].Value.ToString(); ;

            try
            {
                System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
                attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attachFile);


                MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com");


                email.From = new MailAddress(SendMailFrom);
                email.To.Add(SendMailTo);
                email.Subject = SendMailSubject;
                email.Body = SendMailBody;
                email.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                //email.Attachments = attachment;

                // START
                SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SendMailFrom, "Password");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                //END

                SmtpServer.Send(email);

                
                MessageBox.Show("Email was Successfully Sent");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
         

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution (this would replace the credential section):

```
            SmtpServer.Port = 25;
            SmtpServer.Host = "Host Name";
            SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```